# How to pass values to an ASP.Net Core APiController using Postman

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, postman

My project reads several key-values from Postman and generates a JWT
[image]

But I get Error415 after I add `[ApiController]` attribute to the controller code
[image]

Here is my controller code

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    //[ApiController]                  //When I uncomment this attribute, I get Error 415 on postman
    public class AuthController : Controller
    {
        private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public AuthController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> usermanager)
        {
            _userManager = usermanager;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
            if (user != null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
            {
                //get roles and claims of the logged in user
                var _roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
                var _claims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);

                //add roles and claims from DB to JWT claims
                var claims = new List<Claim>();
                foreach (var role in _roles)
                {
                    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
                }

                foreach (var claim in _claims)
                {
                    claims.Add(new Claim(claim.Type, claim.Value));
                }

                //security key
                string _securityKey = "A super secure key";
                //symmetric security key
                var _symmetricSecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_securityKey));
                //signing credentials
                var _signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(_symmetricSecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

                //create token
                var _token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    issuer: "issuer",
                    audience: "audience",
                    expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
                    claims: claims,
                    signingCredentials: _signingCredentials
                    );
                return Ok(new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(_token));
            }
            return Unauthorized();
        }
    }
```

What change to I need to make to make it work with `[ApiController]` added?

Comment: ApiController uses Json by default. You would need to be explicit about where to bind the data from. since form data is being sent then `[FromForm]` attribute will need to be used. ie `Task<IActionResult> Login([FromForm]LoginModel model)`

Comment: Also use `[HttpPost("login")]` instead of both attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `[FromForm]` attribute in order to tell the model binder that it sould read data from form or you can change you request and send your request body as json, just switch to raw in postman and set type to json.

Answer (score 1):

You can set **Content-Type : application/json** in Header tab and in your controller set Login([**FromForm**]LoginModel model) or Login([**FromBody**]LoginModel model) according to from where you want to send data.